# Where can I acquire the Windows 6.0 Bootstrapper files for VS?

Tags: visual-studio, build-error, vs-error

I've **deleted** the Windows 6 SDK folder and now my VS refuses to build my Deployment Project. I need to get the filed back to get working again.

> **Could not find required file** 'setup.bin' in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\ **Windows\v6.0A** \Bootstrapper\Engine'

I've searched around the internet and all I can find are posts which talk of a [specific file being incorrectly deleted](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/34f41417-89b2-48a1-af64-4904c5710e30/) by their anti-virus programs, but no one's really offering those files!

Where can I get these **Windows\v6.0A** SDK files from?

Comment: Just a note, the file isn't normally deleted. It's more often than not quarantined (I just encountered this problem). You can restore files from a quarantine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody suggested:

> Okay, I did a repair install of [VS](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/default.aspx) and
>   that added the folders.

does that help?

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2007/11/30/released-visual-studio-2008-with-embedded-windows-sdk-components.aspx) has brought me to the [download of Windows SDK.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4377F86D-C913-4B5C-B87E-EF72E5B4E065&displaylang=en) *(a combination of Platform SDK and .NET Framework SDK)*

That should re-create these folders.