# Building Visual Studio 2008 Setup projects with the Windows 7 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, winapi

Is it possible to build a Visual Studio 2008 Setup project with only the Windows 7 SDK installed?

My setup project refuses to build because it can't find "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\", part of the Windows 6 SDK. I would have thought that the 7 SDK would have everything that the setup project needs.

A related question: [Where can I aquire the Windows 6.0 Bootstrapper files for VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413005/where-can-i-aquire-the-windows-6-0-bootstrapper-files-for-vs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the files are not really part of the Windows 6 SDK, but part of the Visual Studio 2008 installation. When I removed the Windows 6 SDK I also deleted this folder, thereby causing the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

download the visual studio 2008 service pack 01  with framework 3.5 sp1 redistributable... 
It will solve your problems...