# Where is windows 4.5 bootstrapper package?

Tags: .net, installation

Just got the source files for a setup project that I'm trying to run and I get this warning:

> WARNING: Could not find prerequisite 'Windows Installer 4.5' in path
>   'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\'

I check and of course there is no folder for the 4.5 installer as it says in the warning. I google and find out that I can't download it separately but it's allegedly included in the Visual Studio distribution.

Well... I'm running VS 2008 and it's not there.  I also looked on another computer that I recently installed VS 2008 express on and it's not there either.

Anyone know where I can get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odd problem, that's a Windows SDK version 7 bootstrapper.  Right-click your Setup project, Properties, Prerequisites button. Does it actually appear in the list? Tick 3.1 instead of 4.5 if it does.

Answer (score 1):

Googling "Windows Installer 4.5" turned up http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8483. This seems to be a common problem that affects [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413005/where-can-i-acquire-the-windows-6-0-bootstrapper-files-for-vs) redistributables that specify that directory.

Comment: I don't think this is what I can put in the bootstrapper directory to have the visual studio setup project integrate it into my project though is it?

Answer (score 1):

The 6.0 SDK is for Vista which comes with Windows Installer 4.0. The 4.5 version is distributed by Microsoft as an update.

You can try installing the 7.0 SDK. It's for Windows 7 which comes with Windows Installer 5.0. So it includes a Windows Installer 4.5 prerequisite package.

Basically, when the 6.0 SDK was released Windows Installer 4.5 didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (x86 path though):

> WARNING: Could not find prerequisite 'Windows Installer 4.5' in path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\'

What solved it for me was uninstalling the existing package (via Add or Remove Programs) then rebuilding the installer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I can't see the package in Add/Remove Programs. I tried removing the ClickOnce package using the VS Installer and reinstalling, but it didn't fix the issue. I'm removing VS2019 altoghether and will reinstall it to see if that fixes it.

Quite annoying since everything was working perfectly with VS2017.